# Modify label of command programmatically in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

Is it possible in Eclipse RCP to modify programmatically the label of a command defined in plugin.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way to programmatically change the name of a command defined using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point.

Note that the UI often doesn't use the command name anyway. For example the `command` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point has a `label` attribute which overrides the command name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The label attribute of org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point is also impossible to change programmatically?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve, as this may not be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you do have a handler for the respective command.Ask your handler to implement IElementUpdater and in method

```
updateElement(UIElement element, Map parameters)
```

you can just set the label of menu item as

```
element.setText("any_name");
```